# How can I get a list of all the defined variables in Matlab or Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm used to working in Matlab using its full GUI environment.  Due to license issues I went and installed Octave, but it appears that it doesn't have a GUI, at least not one that's installed by default.

I transferred the variables from Matlab to Octave by `save`ing them in Matlab and `load`ing them in Octave.  Thing is, I don't remember the names because I got used to seeing them in the little workspace window which I no longer have.

How can I see the list of defined variables and their types in Octave?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The command [`whos`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/whos.html) will do just that.

Answer (score 3):

With the command `whos` you can even see the variables that the file has WITHOUT opening the file, to be assure that this file is the one.

For example, the name of the file is MyVariables.mat

use:

```
whos('-file','MyVariables.mat')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GUI similar to Matlab, such as QtOctave or GUIOctave.

Comment: Note: A standard GUI is now being developed (using QT).