# In GNU Octave is there a command to show all the available matrices?

Tags: octave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a list of all the defined variables in Matlab or Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457634/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-defined-variables-in-matlab-or-octave)

I dont have MatLab so I used Octave to import a .mat file by doing load some.mat .

Now how do I know what vectors/matrices have I loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `who` and/or `whos` command, just like matlab.